# Tortoise tts is not using GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, text-to-speech

i have sucesfully installed tortoise TTs and my env looks like this:

```
aiohttp                   3.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
aiosignal                 1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
annotated-types           0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             4.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
audioread                 3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
beartype                  0.16.4                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2023.12.12           haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cloudpickle               3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               11.8.0               hd77b12b_0
dataclasses-json          0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
einops                    0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
frozenlist                1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
fsspec                    2023.12.2                pypi_0    pypi
greenlet                  3.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
huggingface-hub           0.20.2                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
inflect                   5.3.0            py39haa95532_1
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46320
ipykernel                 6.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonpatch                 1.33                     pypi_0    pypi
jsonpointer               2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            6.1.12                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              5.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
langchain                 0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
langchain-community       0.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
langchain-core            0.1.10                   pypi_0    pypi
langsmith                 0.0.80                   pypi_0    pypi
lazy-loader               0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
librosa                   0.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.41.0           py39hf2fb9eb_0
markupsafe                2.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
marshmallow               3.20.2                   pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2023.1.0         h6b88ed4_46358
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py39h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4            py39h59b6b97_0
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack                   1.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 6.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mypy-extensions           1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.5.8                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  3.0                      pypi_0    pypi
numba                     0.58.1           py39hd77b12b_0
numpy                     1.26.3           py39h055cbcc_0
numpy-base                1.26.3           py39h65a83cf_0
openssl                   3.0.12               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    9.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       23.3.1           py39haa95532_0
platformdirs              4.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pooch                     1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pure-eval                 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pydantic                  2.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.14.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.9.18               h1aa4202_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   306                      pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.1.2                   pypi_0    pypi
regex                     2023.12.25               pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rotary-embedding-torch    0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
safetensors               0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.4.0rc1                 pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.12.0rc2                pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.2.2           py39haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
soundfile                 0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
soxr                      0.3.7                    pypi_0    pypi
spyder-kernels            2.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlalchemy                2.0.25                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
stack-data                0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.8.0             h59b6b97_0
tenacity                  8.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tokenizers                0.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
torch                     2.1.2+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.1.2+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.16.2+cu118             pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4                      pypi_0    pypi
tortoise-tts              3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.66.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
transformers              4.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-inspect            0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2023d                h04d1e81_0
unidecode                 1.3.8                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.13                  pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.13                   pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2           py39haa95532_0
yarl                      1.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
```

torch.cuda.is available returns true but when i run tortoise tts it uses only 0.1 percent gpu and 5 percent cpu. this causes it to be unbearably slow even with cuda. why is it not using the gpu??

i tried several things like reinstalling torch and forcefully changing tortoise tts device to cuda:0 but nothing made a difference.